# Discord bot wont respond to messages sent in dms

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have setup all of the required intents including `DIRECT_MESSAGES` though the client messageCreate event doesn't appear to be picking up the command and responded now I checked the bot and the command does indeed work in the guild but for some reason not in dms.

My code block

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    const msg = message
    const args = message.content.slice(1).split(/ +/)
    const args2 = message.content.split(/ +/)
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === '!resetverify') {
      if (!message.author.id === '853322763930828800') return
      db.set("verifyTicketAmount", 0)
      message.reply('Cleared')
    }
  })
```

Comment: This code worked fine for me. Code: https://i.postimg.cc/zf9nVnns/Screenshot-2022-04-14-204748.png Response: https://i.postimg.cc/XYrGdr74/Screenshot-2022-04-14-204937.png. Please update your question with error code.

Comment: the thing is the bot never threw a error code it just didnt scan DMS perhaps you can tell me how you formatted your intents Gh0st

Comment: const bot = new Client({
    intents: 32767,
    partials: ['CHANNEL', 'GUILD_MEMBER', 'GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENT', 'MESSAGE', 'REACTION', 'USER']
})

32767 = all intents

Comment: Let me try that one moment\

Comment: Omg  thanks mate my intents were incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the right intents, I personally use the "all intents" like below

```js
const bot = new Client({
    intents: 131071,
    partials: ['CHANNEL', 'GUILD_MEMBER', 'GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENT', 'MESSAGE', 'REACTION', 'USER']
})
```

You can see all the intents here:
[Intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents)

or use 131071 for all of them

Updated intents include all new intents, 32767 no longer includes all of them